# A song from a play

Tags: poetry

I went to a play recently. Immediately after the intermission, some cast members sang this short (and terribly written) song:

> This treatise we sing on this section of stage
>   is not so long as to discourage.
>   It'll draw all your effort out, lessen your boredom:
>   you'll be like a farm machine, gaining momentum.
>   In summary, this isn't over-hard;
>   your pains of labor'll yield tempting reward.

I spend the second half of the play trying to figure it out and missed the action, and I still haven't got it. Can you figure it out?

---

Hint (added later):

> a song immediately following the intermission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Stiv is *very* close, they are looking at the wrong parts of the words:

> This **treatise** we sing on this **section** of stage = **TRACT**
>  is not so long as to discourage. = UNPRO**TRACT**ED (?)
>  draw all your effort out = EX**TRACT**
>  lessen your boredom = DIS**TRACT**
>  you'll be like a **farm machine**, gaining **momentum** = **TRACT**OR / **TRACT**ION
>  In summary, this **isn't over-hard**; = **TRACT**ABLE
>  your pains of labor'll = CON**TRACT**IONS
>  yield tempting reward. = AT**TRACT**

Thus, I think you actually missed the fact you were listening to an

> En**tr'act**e

Which in many musicals, is what comes first in the second act.

Comment: Nice. Knowledge I didn't have, I'm afraid, so I would not have been able to make that leap! Happy my solution could lead you in the right direction :) Well done, sir. +1

Comment: @Stiv You were so close that at first I almost felt bad using it as a jumping off point for a separate answer, but in the end the difference was too substantive to be a simple edit on your answer.

Comment: Hey, feel no guilt - besides, you spotted extras I hadn't. Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes to spot that missing link and wrap everything up!

Comment: Nicely done. Each line actually has two such words (though one of the twelve hardly) — or is intended to. The intended words: rot13(genpg[ngr], genpg; cebgenpgrq, qvfgenpg; rkgenpg, fhogenpg; genpgbe, genpgvba; nofgenpg, vagenpgnoyr; pbagenpgvbaf, nggenpgvir. Naq bs pbhefr, nf lbh qvfpbirerq, rage'npgr [juvpu vf abg n _genpg_ jbeq ohg jnf guebja va sbe sha].)

Answer (score 6):

(Rearranging my thoughts...) I wonder if the secret to this poem lies in:

> The irony that the writer '*missed the **action***' while musing on the verse, given that the whole thing comprises phrases which lead to definitions of words that end in **ACTION**.

Since:

> - "It'll draw all your effort out" suggests **EXTRACTION**;
>  - "Something which might "lessen your boredom" is a **DISTRACTION**;
>  - A farm machine is a **TRACTION** engine (a word which can also imply 'momentum');
>  - "Pains of labor" are **CONTRACTIONS**;
>  - 'Tempting reward' could be **ATTRACTION**.

Furthermore, the poem also contains several words which are

> CONTRACTIONS:
>
>  **It'll** draw all your effort out, lessen your boredom:
>  **you'll** be like a farm machine, gaining momentum.
>  In summary, this **isn't** over-hard;
>  your pains of **labor'll** yield tempting reward.

Comment: You're getting there. Note that the "answer" need not be a word.

Comment: @msh210 Hmmm... I'll give it some more thought...

Comment: You're getting closer....